# How do I make the autocomplete list for a TextBox editable?

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, autocomplete

I have an application with a lot of `TextBox` controls that use autocomplete.  Each one uses `AutoCompleteMode.CustomSource` to get the autocomplete text from an associated `AutoCompleteStringCollection`.

Whenever the user enters a new value in the `TextBox`, it gets added to the associated `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, and at the end of the session all of those collections get persisted to a file in the user's home directory.

The problem is that there's no way to correct errors in those collections.  In IE, input controls with autocomplete controls let you scroll to an item in the autocomplete list and press `Del` to remove it.  That doesn't work in the .NET controls.

I'd really like to avoid having to implement my own UI for this.  Am I stuck?  Is there a way to enable this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Pardon my naivete, but how are you getting the suggestions?  My only experience in developing an autocomplete is through the ASP.NET AJAX   toolkit, and since that component gets it suggestions from a webservice, I think there would be no way to edit it.

But of course I could be wrong.

Comment: He's using Windows Forms, not ASP.NET, which has built-in support for AutoComplete, from various sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, no there's nothing to do this for you unfortunately. I tried P/Invoking the basic FindWindowEx / EnumChildWindows to see if I can get a Handle to the actual drop down, but was unsuccessful (if someone does manage to pull this off, let me know!). The good news is (not so good, but not terrible) that the auto complete isn't actually something you completely have to implement yourself, there's actually a Win32 function called [SHAutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759862(VS.85).aspx) that can be P/Invoked to help you with the auto completion. Don't get too excited yet, because it's not as simple as just P/Invoking it and be done with it. However, there's a great [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell4.aspx) that should help you out tremendously.

Comment: That's an outstanding article, and thanks.  This is clearly going to take some digging.