# C# How can I get a textbox suggestions list into a list<string>?

Tags: c#, autosuggest

C# How can I get a textbox suggestions list into a list?

e.g. say I do

`textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories`
or
    `textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.RecentlyUsedList`

and

`textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;`

I get suggestions come up in the popup suggestions window for the textbox but can I retrieve those suggestions in a list?

Comment: Please, check MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 AutoCompleteSource is a collection of strings ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos it's an enum. I don't know how to get the strings in an IEnumerable or Array

Comment: Do you mean `FileSystemDirectories` and `RecentlyUsedList`? So, you want to get these values?

Comment: you can loop through an enum using a for loop.

Comment: @gmiley would looping through the RecentlyUsedList enum produce a set of strings each string being a path.. ?  If so then yes I'd want to.  If not then no I don't want to.

Comment: Looping through it produces whatever is in each item of the enumeration. If you set a breakpoint on the `RecentlyUsedList` and inspect the contents, what is in there?

Comment: @gmiley I don't know much about enums and I doubt your idea is going to work, but i'm trying it. I'm not sure how though since RecentlyUsedList   is not an enum it's an AutoCompleteSource  and AutoCompleteSource is an enum(as contradictory as that sounds). Anyhow,  I get a compilation error when I try `            foreach (AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories foo in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories)))
            {

            }`

Comment: Actually, after looking at it myself, you will want the AutoCompleteStringCollection. You can loop through that or access it as a `List` since it implements `IList`. You can do a `foreach(string item in textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource) { /* ... */ }` so long as you are using: `AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource'. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletestringcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575585/windows-forms-open-suggestions-list-programatically-after-setting-the-autocomp

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947546/how-do-i-make-the-autocomplete-list-for-a-textbox-editable There's a link to CP article, which explains how AutoComplete feature works.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set up your `TextBox` in the following manner:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
// Add each item to the collection
source.Add("some string");
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
```

Then you can access the items wherever else by doing the following:

```
foreach(string item in textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Or however you want, textBox.AutoCompleteSource is defined now as a class that implements `IList`, `ICollection`, and `IEnumerable`. So you can use any methods that would access a `List`, `Collection`, or `Enumeration`. It's up to you.

To summarize the comments below, to access the list of items in auto-complete for anything other than the `CustomSource`, you would likely need to hook into the Windows API, or maybe use reflection (though that is unlikely, Windows API would be the most likely to work).

Comment: I can get this to work `            foreach (string item in textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource)            
                tb.Text+=item;`   But I cannot get this to work for ` foreach (string item in textBox.AutoCompleteSource)
                tb.Text += item;`  e.g. where the AutoCompleteSource might not be custom..

Comment: `AutoCompleteSource` is just the property to define what kind of source the `TextBox` will use, it does not contain any of the auto-complete items that would display to the user as they type. `AutoCompleteCustomSource` is what contains the list of items. Take a look at the MSDN entry for it, it provides a list of values that can be assigned to `AutoCompleteSource`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: so your one is only working for a custom list, which I can have anyway without even needing to get it from a textbox. But it's not getting the suggestions when the suggestions aren't custom.. e.g. when the suggestions are   e.g. `AutoCompleteSource.RecentlyUsedList`

Comment: I don't think a list is accessible when using `RecentlyUsed` option. You may be able to look into something using `Reflection`, but I would suggest using the `CustomSource` option and storing/populating the list yourself.

Comment: Well, there's no benefit to getting it from the textbox suggestion window when it's a custom list, because the custom list would be something i'd build so i'd have the list.  My question was asking giving the examples of most recently used(which you think is not possible), and of the directories `AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories`

Comment: I believe it uses built in windows information. That's why I think the only way  you might be able to access it would be through reflection. Or maybe hooking into the windows API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111320/discussion-between-barlop-and-gmiley).

Answer (score 1):

To reach this result:

[image]

you can follow two ways, the firs by environment Properties tab and
setting the follows properties:

[image]

The best way is create this effect by code, see my example as a follows:

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection sourceName = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

foreach (string name in listNames)
{    
    sourceName.Add(name);
}

txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sourceName;
txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: it has been a while since I looked into this but part of what you have posted here looks very much like what gsmiley suggested, and it looks like I took issue with that, Have you addressed those issues?

Comment: @barlop I have specified two ways. Both through the IDE and through the code. The answer is different, for me more clarifier.

Comment: If you read the comments on that other answer, as suggested, then you'd see I wrote  "so your one is only working for a custom list, which I can have anyway without even needing to get it from a textbox. But it's not getting the suggestions when the suggestions aren't custom.. e.g. when the suggestions are e.g. AutoCompleteSource.RecentlyUsedList"   I look at your code and it says `txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;`  and it says an equivalent thing in your GUI example, referencing a custom source not the RecentlyUsedList.

Comment: So your answer doesn't address the problem that I mentioned with the other answer, and simply shares that problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my research, i do believe that there's no direct way to get list of suggestions for `TextBox` control with `AutoCompleteSource` set to one of defined values.

The author of answer for this question: [How do I make the autocomplete list for a TextBox editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947546/how-do-i-make-the-autocomplete-list-for-a-textbox-editable) suggest to read CP's article: [C# does Shell, Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3792/C-does-Shell-Part) to be able to use `AutoComplete` to expand strings written in an edit box.

Comment: a commenter on part 1 of c# does shell  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3551/C-does-Shell-Part    comment by tatworth  mentioned https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2005/11/18/dont-do-shell-extension-handlers-in-net/       Do you think there's thus any danger in that code in that codeproject project?

Comment: @barlop, you're very welcome. There's no danger to use code provided by the author of article, thought. Today a .net framework has many security updates uncluded.

Comment: can you explain what danger that link is talking about and why it doesn't apply to that codeproject author's code?

Comment: also a bunch of links in part1 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3551/C-does-Shell-Part of that project are broken. e.g. he says a prerequisite is to read msdn links of `Shell Programmer's Guide` and `Shell Basics` and `The Shell Namespace`  and a bunch of others, and theyre all broken links.

Comment: Start here for `Shell Developer's Guide`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Other links are available via Google when you type the title of related MSDN article.